# I get this Quota error for 'logging.googleapis.com/read_requests'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

What is the exact limit to increase in GCP to get rid of this error ?

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 429,
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Insufficient tokens for quota 'logging.googleapis.com/read_requests' and limit 'ReadRequestsPerMinutePerUser' of service 'logging.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:225258829199'.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "rateLimitExceeded"
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are hitting the 20 QPS max requests quota. Try checking how many read/write requests you've been doing. It's unlikely this will get increased.

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/compute.googleapis.com/quotas?project=<INSERT MY PROJECT NUMBER>&duration=P30D
```