# How to determine what quota I'm violating?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-stackdriver

Ok, so I'm developing an application for eventual deployment to App Engine and I'm working locally, on my laptop, and I keep getting these errors:

```
Insufficient tokens for quota 'logging.googleapis.com/read_requests' and limit 'ReadRequestsPerMinutePerProject' of service 'logging.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:111111111'.
```

So how would I sort out which quota I'm violating? I logged into the GCP console and I click the `APIs & Services` > `Dashboard`. But none of the graph numbers are anywhere near their quota limits. (example, the graph shows 5 "Read requests" and the `Read requests per 100 seconds` quota next to it says 2,000).

I thought it might be in the `IAM & Admin` > `Quotas` section, but nothing there is even remotely close to being violated and it is sorted on "Used".

With that all said, how do I look at this error message and match it to a "Quota" in the console?

For what it's worth, this is a small Node.js app and I'm using the `@google-cloud/logging` and `@google-cloud/compute` packages. My laptop is a Macbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the project number in the error whether it matches with your project number. The quota limit you are hitting may not be from your own projects as you are saying you could not see any ‘Quota’ reached its limit.

Validate whether you are using a service account that is tied to a different project to do the calls to the API, 'Quota' could be reached at that project as well.

You can also look at this link where a user was facing similar error [1].

[1] [I get this Quota error for 'logging.googleapis.com/read_requests'](https://serverfault.com/questions/880831/i-get-this-quota-error-for-logging-googleapis-com-read-requests)

Comment: Ah, I see. The "project_number" is found in the IAM & admin > Settings page. So I am looking at the right project, but the APIs & Services > Quotas (which seems to be the place your related link sends me) doesn't show anything in violation. Everything is an order of magnitude lower than the corresponding quota limits.

Comment: Did you mean the project number at the error matches with you own project number? Existing Quota can be checked at Cloud Console from 'IAM & Admin' page then clicking on 'Quotas'.

Comment: Yes, I didn't realize there was a Project ID as well as a project number. I did confirm it was the "Read Requests" quota, but I'm still confused as to why I'm violating it. But that seems to be another question, so I'll accept this answer.